# Using egyptian transliteration in LaTeX as unicode

Tags: unicode

I am trying to use Egyptian transliteration letters in LaTeX, for example Ꜣ which is U+A722 in unicode. The usual workarounds for using unicode letters in LaTeX did not work for this case and I don't know whether there is any quick fix, but I am happy for every suggestion.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)! it can help to have a search about using [xetex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xetex) or [luatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luatex) for compilation.

Comment: Do you have access to a font contains all the necessary glyphs/letters?

Comment: It should be in DejaVu Sans and FreeSerif among others: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a723/fontsupport.htm

Comment: Then the easiest solution is to use either XeTeX or LuaTeX (with LaTeX, that means compiling with the commands `xelatex` or `lualatex` and using the `fontspec` package).  Would that work?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}
\section{unicode test}

Ꜣ

\end{document}`

Comment: That code did the trick, I have no idea why it didn't work previously... Btw it was compiled with xelatex. Thank you jon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this does the trick:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

    \begin{document}
    \section{unicode test}

    Ꜣ

    \end{document}
```

And then compiling it with xelatex. Thank you jon for the suggestions!

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Glad it was that easy!